# Does JFS work like the ext3 writeback mode or the ordered mode?

Tags: filesystems, ext3, journaling

I know that the Journaled File System (JFS) does only journaling of the metadata.

But does JFS under Linux work like the ext3 **writeback** mode or like the **ordered** mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to ordered mode as per [Journaling file systems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/linux390/perf/tuning_res_journaling.html).

So it works like ordered mode.

For a more detailed comparison you can browse the source of [inode.c for JFS](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/jfs/inode.c) and [inode.c for ext3](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext3/inode.c),  along with other files in the respective filesystem directories.